# how to resolve native gem dependencies for AWS Lambda function?

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, ruby-2.5

I am using serverless framework with 'aws-ruby' template.
In my Gemfile i have pg and nokogiri gem.

When I run `'bundle install --deployment'`, it actually creates a vendor folder in my current working directory and also build the dependency based on my local system environment.

I am having issue related to native extension error on AWS environment when i run my lambda function.

Any idea how can i resolve the native dependencies of ruby gems on AWS lambda environment?

Answer (score 2):

A pattern I’m seeing quite a lot is to build your function and its dependencies in a Docker container based on Amazon Linux (e.g. that OS that your function will be running on in Lambda): check out [this blog post](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/12/deploying-native-nodejs-dependencies-aws-lambda/) for a walkthrough and some examples.

[Another example project is here](https://github.com/chief-wizard/serverless-nodejs-image-resizing).